# Javascript - how to use an imported module in Node.js

Tags: import, es6-modules

Here is my `package.json` :

```
"name": "api_geoservices",
"version": "1.0.0",
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
"start": "vite",
"build": "vite build",
"serve": "vite preview",
"test": "node test.js"
},
"devDependencies": {
"vite": "^4.0.4"
},
"dependencies": {
"@turf/centroid": "^6.5.0",
"ol": "latest",
"ol-ext": "^4.0.13",
"proj4": "^2.9.2"
 }
}
```

You can see that the centroid module is installed.

In main.js, I am using the `centroid` module like this:

```
*imports*
import centroid from "@turf/centroid"
...
const featuresPoint = []
turf.featureEach(reponse, function (operation) {
  const centroide = turf.centroid(operation)
  const pointCentroid = opeGeoJsonFormat.readFeature(centroide)
  featuresPoint.push(pointCentroid)
....
})
```

In the browser, the console logs out `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: turf is not defined`. It seems that `turf` is not a global variable. Fine.   So how to use the imported module correctly and not using cdn link in the html file? I can't see what I missed in the [doc](https://turfjs.org/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You use:

```
turf.featureEach & turf.centroid
```

but you imported centroid:

```
import centroid from "@turf/centroid"
```

**Refined Explanation:**

- **Emphasize Direct Import:** "You've imported the `centroid` function directly from the `@turf/centroid` module. This means you can use it without the `turf.` prefix."
- **Example Usage:**

  ```js
  const centroide = centroid(operation); // Using the imported 'centroid'
  ```

You can use import dirrectly from @turf/turf:

```js
import { featureEach, centroid } from '@turf/turf'; // Option A

// ... your code

const featuresPoint = [];
featureEach(response, function (operation) { // Use featureEach
  const centroide = centroid(operation);      // Use centroid
  const pointCentroid = opeGeoJsonFormat.readFeature(centroide);
  featuresPoint.push(pointCen`enter code here`troid);
});
```

Comment: sure, but in this case, how can I use the `featureEach` method belonging to turf module?

Comment: I answer myself : `const centroids = reponse.features.map(feature => centroid(feature))` is the way I found to use centroid.